# count only if field has one entry in Tableau

Tags: data-visualization, business-intelligence, data-analysis, tableau-api

I am using tableau and am stuck in making the field of the following code unique.

```
"COUNTD(
IF NOT(ISNULL([firstBillingDate]))
THEN [msisdn]
ELSE NULL
END
)"
```

Basically its counting unique `msisdn`'s for all the columns which have firstbillingDate present (NOT NULL).

The problem is that one `msisdn` has more than one `firstBillingDate`. I want to count unique `msidns` which has only ONE `firstbillingdate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using [firstBillingDate] in that calculation, create an LOD calc to only retrieve one date per msisdns.

`{fixed [msisdns] : min([firstBillingDate]}`

You can use `max` or `min`. I assumed you'd want min to return the earlier date for any multiple dates per msisdns. Now use this in your original calc.